# Printing a list in the following format <word>:<number> in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering how I could print the following list

```
mylist=[['carrot', 10], ['potatoe', 8], ['apple', 23]]
```

in the following format

```
<carrot>:<10>
<potatoe>:<8>
<apple>:<23>
```

Comment: Can you show us your attempt at solving this task?

Comment: You iterate through the list and print each item in the given format. Which part are you stuck at?

Comment: This can be done with a simple loop over the elements, some indexing to the first and second element of each inner list, some concatenation between those inner twined with normal text and casting the second element to a string using the str() function. This question shouldn't be answered since SO is not a code delivery tool.

Comment: I think you've got the [Dan Quayle language pack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wdqbi66oNuI) installed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can easily iterate over it and do it. Here's a sample implementation

```
mystring = "\n".join(["<{0}>:<{1}>".format(*lst) for lst in mylist])
print(mystring)
```

Comment: Not downvoted yet, but it's a bad question, and answering it encourages bad questions.

Comment: I have seen answers to questions how to do 'git push origin master' with 10000 upvotes. How's to to say what questions are worth answering and what are not?

Comment: For few reasons: 1) it's not optimal since it creates unnecessary lists, 2) it's not pythonic, 3) it's just a spoon-feeding kind of answer, 4) as mentioned two times, this question should not be answered.

Comment: @bereal May I know why it is not pythonic

Comment: Compare your solution to `'\n'.join(['<{0}>:<{1}>'.format(*x) for x in mylist])`.

Comment: Because it's syntactically noisy and not straightforward. Pythonic way could be something like `for lst in mylist: print '<{0}>:<{1}>'.format(*lst)`

Comment: @vaultah I agree with you, I should have refined my answer

Comment: @bereat how looping and printing more pythonic, then generating a string and printing it

Comment: @hspandher that part depends on the size of the list and one's ideas of readability (the same two lines, but the information is distributed evenly among them). btw, in the new version of the code `[]` are redundant, no need to have an intermediate list.

Comment: @bereal Let's agree to disagree

Comment: hspandher thanks for your help. @bereal just for my future reference, why should’t the question be answered?

Comment: @TJR because if you have any plans to develop as a programmer, you're supposed to apply own efforts before asking to write a particular narrow-scoped piece of code for you. Even if you try to generalise your question to "how to format data in Python", mighty Google will give you a bunch of good answers. Sorry, I don't mean being rude, in case if that sounds like that.

Comment: @bereal Thank you for the advice. I’m still trying to learn, i’ve been working on this code hw for 2 straight days, and that was the final piece to the puzzel. I’ll keep your advice in mind the next time i ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple `for` loop as follows:

```
mylist = [['carrot', 10], ['potatoe', 8], ['apple', 23]]

for entry, quantity in mylist:
    print '<{}>:<{}>'.format(entry, quantity)
```

Giving you the following output:

```
<carrot>:<10>
<potatoe>:<8>
<apple>:<23>
```